# Add active class on pagination when corresponding slide is showing

Tags: javascript

I have a simple image slider, with pagination controls.
I have coded it to add and remove an "active" class on the pagination
buttons on click. I would also like them to have the active class when the corresponding slide is showing.
How can I modify my code to achieve this?

```
<div id="slideshow">
<ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide showing">
    <div class="slide-description">
      <h1 class="slide-title">All-in-one EV charging solution.</h1>
      <p> Easy to use. Connected with smart charging capabilities. Our charging stations can be used at home,
        work or in public.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
      <div class="slide-description">
        <h1 class="slide-title">Charging at work- a case study.</h1>
        <p>In this new series of charging case studies, we dive into into the reasons why EV-Box partners are taking the green route.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">  <div class="slide-description">
      <h1 class="slide-title">Finding the best solution for your charging routine.</h1>
      <p>
        This whitepaper highlights the key answers that will guide you to acharging solution that best serves your needs.
      </p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
    <button class="controls" id="previous"></button>
  <button class="controls" id="next"></button>
  <div id="pagination"></div>



var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide'); // get all the slides
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 6000);

function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function previousSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

//Previous and Next controls
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
  nextSlide();
};

previous.onclick = function() {
  previousSlide();
};

//Pagination controls
var p = document.getElementById('pagination');
var phtml = '';

for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  phtml += '<button></button>'; // create the pagination buttons for each slide
}
p.innerHTML = phtml; //insert the html for the buttons

var pbuttons = p.querySelectorAll('button'); // grab all the buttons
var activeButton = null; // reference to active button

for(var i = 0; i < pbuttons.length; i++) {
  pbuttons[i].onclick = (function(n) {

    return function() {
      if(activeButton)
      activeButton.classList.remove('active'); // delete class from old active button
      activeButton = this;// change ref, this is current button
      activeButton.classList.add('active');// add class for new
      goToSlide(n);
    };
  })(i);
}



#slider {
  min-height: 400px;
  position: relative;

  #slides {
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;

    .slide {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: 1;
      min-height: 400px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background: $black;
      color: $white;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
      justify-content: flex-end;

      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
      -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
      transition: opacity 1s;

      &.showing {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        @include backImage('../images/evbox1.jpg');
      }
      &:nth-of-type(2){
        @include backImage('../images/evbox2.jpg');
      }
      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        @include backImage('../images/evbox3.jpg');
      }
    }

    .slide-description {
      width: 500px;

      .slide-title {
        width: 90%;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 44px;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba($black, .2);
        line-height: 1.1em;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      p {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba($black, .2);
      }
      .btn {
        @include button($blue, $font-color, $shadow-color);
      }
    }

    @include respond-to($mobile) {
      @media only screen and (max-width: $mobile) {
        .slide:nth-of-type(3) {
          background-position: left 0;
        }
        .slide-description {
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 8em 5em;
          position: static;
          text-align: center;

          .slide-title {
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 100%;
          }

          .btn {
            padding: 8px 16px;
          }
        }
        p {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


/*Previous and Next Controls*/
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  z-index: 10;
  background: url('http://www.ev-box.com/Evbox-EN/includes/themes/evbox/assets/images/sprites@2x.png') no-repeat;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  background-size: 369px 240px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#previous {
  right: 10px;
  background-position: -50px -121px;
}

#next {
  left: 10px;
  background-position: -16px -121px;
}

// Pagination
#pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 10;

  button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid $white;
    background-color: $white;
    opacity: .8;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    min-height: 14px;
    border-width: 0;
    margin-right: 5px;

    &.active {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      min-height: 15px;
      border: 1px solid $white;
      background-color: $primary;
      opacity: 1;

      &:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the javascript as shown below. Use this in your code pen. you can see the diffrence. If you click next and previous button the corresponding pagination will be highlighted by using this javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide'); // get all the slides
const totalSlides = 2 // Total number of slides count
var currentSlide = 0; // current slide 
var previousSlide = totalSlides;

 // var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 1000);

 function nextSlide() {
   previousSlide = currentSlide
   if(totalSlides > currentSlide){
   currentSlide += 1
 }
   else currentSlide = 0
   goToSlide();
 }

function PreviousSlide() {
      if(currentSlide == 0){
        previousSlide = currentSlide
        currentSlide = totalSlides
      }
      else{
          previousSlide = currentSlide
         currentSlide -=1
       }
      goToSlide();
}


function goToSlide() {
  slides[previousSlide].className = 'slide';
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  var currentSlideButton = "button"+currentSlide
  var previousSlideButton = "button"+previousSlide
  document.getElementById(currentSlideButton).classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById(previousSlideButton).classList.remove('active');
}

//Previous and Next controls
var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
  PreviousSlide();
};

previous.onclick = function() {

  nextSlide();

};

//Pagination controls
var p = document.getElementById('pagination');
var phtml = '';

for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  phtml += '<button id=button'+i+'></button>'; // create the pagination buttons for each slide
}
p.innerHTML = phtml; //insert the html for the buttons

var pbuttons = p.querySelectorAll('button'); // grab all the buttons
var activeButton = null; // reference to active button

for(var i = 0; i < pbuttons.length; i++) {
  pbuttons[i].onclick = (function(n) {
    return function() {
      if(activeButton)
      activeButton.classList.remove('active'); // delete class from old active button
      activeButton = this;// change ref, this is current button
      activeButton.classList.add('active');// add class for new
      goToSlide(n);
    };
  })(i);
}
goToSlide();// Initialising goToSlide method

});
```

Comment: Thanks Hari. But that is not exactly what I meant. I would like the pagination controls to also have an active class when the corresponding slide is showing, and not only when the user clicks the pagination controls. It is an auto slider you see.

Comment: ok. you are adding 3 buttons in   <div id="pagination"></div> for 3 slides. you want any one of the button by default as active. I'm i right.

Comment: The pagination active does work. But I would like it to be active when the correct slide is displaying too, as seen here for example. http://www.ev-box.com/

Comment: Hari, I have added the CSS (Sass) below the JS

Comment: I want to see your entire coding(related to Pagination especially CSS) to solve this. your question does not have any CSS. I saw the link you were given. I can understand what you are trying to do but I don't know the actual output whcih you are seeing

Comment: `code`#pagination {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 50%;
  z-index: 10; }
  #pagination button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: .8;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    min-height: 14px;
    border-width: 0;
    margin-right: 5px; }
    #pagination button.active {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      min-height: 15px;
      border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
      background-color: #41b54c;
      opacity: 1; }
      #pagination button.active:focus {
        outline: 0; } `code`

Comment: @madameFerry, I updated the answer,  This will make your current slide to be active when it is displaying

Comment: That is useful however I need the pagination button to be active not the current slide... just as seen here http://www.ev-box.com/

Comment: add your code in codepen and explain it. You said button should be active when the correct slide is displaying. I can't understand what you seen in the slider of ev-box.com and what you want in your program. You are saying pagination button to be active "Not" on the current slide. In that case when it should be active

Comment: Here is my codepen. When the user uses the previous and next controls, I would like the pagination buttons to have a class of "active". As it is an autoslider,  I would expect to have the corresponding pagination button be active as well. http://codepen.io/ginalolli/pen/WpomVZ